# SQL Missing record issues

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Hi all apologies for the stupid question but I am having an issue with a query and hoping that you guys can point me in the right direction- please have patience I am a complete beginner.
I have three tables setup that look roughly as follows:

```
table 1 quizquestions
Question ID, etc.
Int

table 2 quizanswers
AnswerID, QuestionID,correct Answer
Int         Int         Bool

table 3 useranswers
UserAnswerID, AnswerID, QuestionID
Int                Int         Int
```

my issue is when I run a query such as this:

```
SELECT A.AnswerID AS Answer, UA.AnswerID AS UserAnswer 
FROM quizanswers AS A, useranswers UA 
WHERE A.CorrectAnswer = TRUE 
  AND UA.QuestionID 
  AND  A.QuestionID = X
```

the Query will return a result like the following:

```
Answer UserAnswer 
  1        1
```

the query will successfully return a result if there is a record in both the quizanswers and the useranswers table. However the issue is when there isn't a record within the useranswers table no result is returned whatsoever. I apologise if the code above is not clear enough, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get the business case behind the question, but this will give you the records from quizanswers even if there is no correspondning record in useranswers:

```
    SELECT A.AnswerID AS Answer, UA.AnswerID AS UserAnswer FROM quizanswers AS A LEFT JOIN useranswers UA ON UA.QuestionID = A.QuestionD WHERE A.CorrectAnswer = TRUE AND A.QuestionID = X
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work in MSSQL I'm sure I don't have the correct Null function for MySQL, but the logic should be the same.

```
SELECT A.AnswerID AS Answer, UA.AnswerID AS UserAnswer 
FROM quizanswers AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN useranswers UA 
 ON UA.QuestionID = A.QuestionID
WHERE ISNULL(A.CorrectAnswer, FALSE) = TRUE
```